# How to connect Mongoose backend class to frontend class (Ionic with Angular.io)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mongoose

I've been trying for way too many hours now, and I simply cannot get this to work. I'm making a login page, where you basically just insert the username and it then fetches the information from the database and updates the object on the frontend (only difference is the ObjectID has been added). Here's what I want:

1. Load the login page, which prompts you to enter an username.
2. You enter the username. Multiple things can happen here:

   1. It creates a new entry in the database with the new username and returns the new user with: `ObjectID` and `Username`
   2. It returns the entry from the database (from `find()`)

This is nothing crazy, but I simply cannot get past an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null

**login.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-input placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="user.username"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</ion-content>
```

**login.ts**

```
export class LoginPage {
  appStorage: Storage;
  user = {
    id: "test",
    username: "test"
  };
  //user: User;
  //user: Object = {};

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.appStorage = storage;

    storage.get('user').then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.appStorage.set("user", this.user);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = {
      id: "test",
      name: "test"
    };
  }
}
```

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
    public id: string;
    public username: string;

    constructor(public inputId?: string, public inputUsername?: string) {
        this.id = inputId;
        this.username = inputUsername;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing around the User class I have, I've tried moving everything into a component, I've tried all sorts of things, but I simply cannot get this to work. I want my backend Mongoose class to match the frontend. Is there a library that can do this for me, perhaps? Otherwise I'll just make them seperately.

I would really like to use the User class I have, so I'm not using objects.

Comment: `user` might be being set to `null` in your `storage.get('user')...` do you get anything if you `console.log(user)` inside the `then` callback?

Comment: @Und3rTow Aaaah that's where the problem is. Works fine now - thanks. Now another issue: Is my User class done correctly? I can't seem to set it as a return type in the `storage.get()`.

Comment: @Und3rTow Okay, so if I use it as an interface instead, how would I basically say `storage.get().then((user: User) => { if(user) { this.user = user} else { this.user = new User(); }});` - basically check if the storage has an user. If it does not, set it to an empty user. Otherwise I will get the same error.

Comment: You could do something like this I guess: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk6yh1

Comment: @Und3rTow I simply set `this.username = ""` in the constructor, then I could do `new User()` and now I'm not getting any errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be doing that. You should use an API to talk to your back-end; and you may re-use your POJO interfaces if you need to; but not access `mongoosejs` storage from your front-end code.